# css how to stretch center div to fill allowable area

Tags: html, css

I have a three column layout. My center div is my main content area. I would like that when my content is not wide this div stretches to fill the available space horizontally and while not critical it would be nice to have it stretch vertically also. I used an online layout [generator](http://www.cssportal.com/layout-generator/) to create this style. See the attached image [image: center div not streched]

Any help would be apreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>CSS Portal - Layout</title>
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<STYLE>
/*    Generated by http://www.cssportal.com    */

@import url("reset.css");

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#333
}

p {
    padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerwrap {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    height: 75px;
    background: #FF6633;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eb521f;
    margin: 5px;
}

#navigationwrap {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation {
    height: 40px;
    background: #FFCC33;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ebb81f;
    margin: 5px;
}

#contentliquid {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#contentwrap {
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    background: #FF724F;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eb5e3b;
    margin: 5px;
}

#leftcolumnwrap {
    width: 150px;
    margin-left:-100%;
    float: left;
}

#leftcolumn {
    background: #33CCFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1fb8eb;
    margin: 5px;
}

#rightcolumnwrap {
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    float: left;
}

#rightcolumn {
    background: #CC33FF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #b81feb;
    margin: 5px;
}

#footerwrap {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: #33FF66;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1feb52;
    margin: 5px;
}
</STYLE>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerwrap">
        <div id="header">

            <?PHP include 'header_page.php'; ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="navigationwrap">
        <div id="navigation">


        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentliquid"><div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="content">

            <?PHP include 'main.php'; ?>

        </div>
        </div></div>
        <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
        <div id="leftcolumn">

            <?PHP include 'left.php'; ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcolumnwrap">
        <div id="rightcolumn">

            <?PHP include 'right.php'; ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerwrap">
        <div id="footer">

            <?PHP include 'footer.php'; ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pleas, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: Work with relative widths, so instead of using pixels (like width: 150px) use something like percentages (like width: 20%). To get you started: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `flex` layout to solve it, [here you can find an example](http://codepen.io/marcomarasco/pen/dYZbpM) .